# Application Request Routing on local machine

Tags: arr

I installed ARR on my local machine and setup a server farm with a single server in it (localhost). I added two redirect routing rules.  However, it doesn't do the redirect.  My Default Web Site has ab additional binding like this one: localhost.mycompany.com.  I tried putting that in the server farm and it still didn't work.  The redirect rules look like this.

Uses wildcards in the pattern

```
inbound pattern:  */path2/*/*/*/method*
Redirect URL: /path1/path2/api/item/method
```

**EDIT:** When I use the Test Pattern and enter one of the URLs against my rule it parses it successfully

Also tried putting the full hostname (e.g. http://localhost.mycompany.com/...) in the redirect rule as well as using the alias *localServerFarm* (which is the name of server farm).  Nothing worked.

The module is "working" in some respect because when I had a broken rule it sure told me about it when I tried to load any url on localhost.  Once I fixed the rule, I no longer got the error message but it doesn't do any redirection.

[image: Server farm setup]

Answer (score 0):

This was just a matter of getting the redirect rule correct.  In the rules list there is a column named Input and it's setting is **URL Path**.  So, the only input to the pattern match is the path part of the URL not including the `/` at the beginning.  All I had to do was change the `*/` at the beginning of my pattern to just `*`, e.g. `*/path2/*/*/*/method*` changed to `*path2/*/*/*/method*`.

I don't know if there's any other setting for the Input field (it isn't settable in the rule definition screen) but for anyone creating rules remember that only the path without a leading `/` is what's used for evaluating the pattern match.   One note is that if you're matching from the beginning of the path, as I am, you don't need the `*` at the beginning of the pattern.  However, if you go into the test pattern screen and paste a full URL into the Input data it will not just grab the path part of that URL and feed it to the pattern match will use the entire string so it will require an `*` at the beginning of your pattern to work.